# Is there Electric Flux through a closed loop around a current wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, maxwell-equations, displacement-current

In one of his lectures, Professor Walter Lewin is ammending Ampère's Law to include displacement current (i.e. It not only depends on the current that penetrates the loop, but also on the changing electric field.)

For this he has a capacitor inbetween a wire with a current, and he shows that the magnetic field B on a point above the wire is the same whether he chooses an open surface that goes inbetween the capacitor or a flat, circular surface that stays around the wire.

He says that, for a given point P above the wire (for which he chooses a circular, flat Amperian loop around the wire first,
with radius coinciding with distance to P) the magnetic field B does not take into account the displacement current, because the Electric Flux is zero!

How can the Electric Flux be zero through that closed loop? There is an Electric Field inside the conducting wire going through the loop!

2 or 3 people asked him in the comments and he said he couldn't give any more clarity.

https://youtu.be/3sP9kh4xtKo it's between 10:20 and 11:00

Answer (score 1):

In slowly variable fields, the conduction current $\gamma \overrightarrow{E}$ is very large compared to the current of displacement ${{\varepsilon }_{0}}\frac{\partial \overrightarrow{E}}{\partial t}\approx {{\varepsilon }_{0}}\frac{E}{\tau }$within the conductor. And the immediatly field outside the conductor is a priori of the same order of magnitude.

To simplify things, one solution is to assume that the conductivity of the metal is very large. At the limit of infinite conductivity, the electric field in the metallic conductor is zero.

Comment: I see. Sorry if I didn't understand the answer, but assuming that the conductivity of the conductor is infinite, and therefore the field is zero, what force drives  the current if not the electric field?

Comment: For high conductivity, a very small electric field drive a finite current. In the course of electromagnetism, when we are in the approximation of quasi-stationary regimes, it is common to assume (more or less implicitly) that the electric field is zero everywhere except between the plates of a capacitor. In reality, there is an electric field connected to the electric current but its distribution outside the conductors is complicated. In practice, this field is most often negligible. Especially since the conductor conductivity is high.

Answer (score -1):

As M. Fraticelli describes, there IS an electric field in the wire, and as the capacitor charges up, that electric field DOES change, so there IS a displacement current.  But as he also said, the displacement current is VERY small compared to the conduction current.  Young and Freedman, 13th edition, chapter 29, problem 45 asks you to calculate the displacement current for a copper wire and show that the magnetic field contribution from the displacement current is insignificant.

Comment: What does this add that the existing answer does not?