# Electric field lines from a time varying current through an infinite wire

Tags: electromagnetism

Considering an infinitely long wire with a current I(t) which varies as a function of sin(t), what (if any) would the electric field lines look like? I understand from magneto-statics there are no electric field lines outside the wire. But looking at the integral form of Ampere's law with Maxwell's correction, I am trying to find the electric field flux through a surface bounded by the Amperian loop.

At first I was thinking that there were no E-Field lines and that this term goes to zero, but then we are back at the case of Ampere's law of magnetostatics. Surely this can't be correct? As there is a time varying current.

Comment: That's a really good question. I found something that might help. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457485/is-there-electric-flux-through-a-closed-loop-around-a-current-wire According to Fraticelli's answer there would be a small electric flux inside the wire in real life, but to make things simpler we assume the wire has infinite conductivity and therefore zero electric flux inside.